# Convert Lightswitch app from VB.Net to C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, lightswitch-2012, vb.net-to-c#

I'm working with a Lightswitch application that is using **VB.Net*.  Although no code has been written yet, there might be some auto-created by Lightswitch.

Now I want to add some code to the project but want the whole thing to use **C#** instead of **VB.Net.**

I don't want to recreate my entire project from scratch.  Is there a way of changing the language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a project from one language to another by right-clicking on the project in SharpDevelop 4 and choosing 'convert':

[image]

You can also try these web-based VB-to-C# tools:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/bulk/

http://converter.telerik.com/

The tool at the first link aims to actually convert an uploaded project from one language to another, while the tool at the second link allows the conversion of code that you paste into a text window.